# How to run a sketch for a period (e.g. 1min) and then attiny85 goes to sleepmode automaticaly?

Tags: attiny85

Another beginner to arduino device.
My knowledge for programming is so weak.
As i mention to the title i would like your help.
I just want to run this simple sketch into attiny85 for lets say 1 min and then chip goes to sleepmode by its own.
My code is below but i cannot manage to achive what i want.
Any help?
Many thanks.

```cpp
void setup() {

  pinMode(0, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);    
  
  
}

void loop() {
  
                              // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  pinMode(0, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);

  
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);  // 1
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(180);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, HIGH);   // 2
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(180);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);      //3
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(180);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);   //4
  digitalWrite(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(180);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);   //5
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  delay(180);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);   //4
  digitalWrite(2, INPUT);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(180);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);     //3
  digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(180);
  digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, HIGH);   // 2
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);
  delay(180);
  digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);  // 1
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);

  
}
```

Comment: I'd start by turning your sets of five `digitalWrite` into a call to single function that takes the number given in the comment.

Comment: where is your attempt to put the device to sleep? ... you presented only unrelated code ... please present minimal code that demonstrates the problem ... that means, have code for only one LED

Comment: Hello,thanks both for your replies. This is my main sketch code. No attempt to put chip in sleepmode yet. Then its better to read more about commands, try to put attiny to sleepmode and revert. Maybe its to early for questions. thnx guys.

Comment: @GEORGEBOULIS I think that I have seen several tutorials about ATTiny85 sleep modes ... perhaps that can be your start

Comment: Thanks once again.

Answer (score 3):

You can write, at the end of `loop()`, “if one minute has elapsed, then
go to sleep”. In C++, that would be:

```cpp
if (millis() >= 60000)  // 60 seconds elapsed
    sleep_mode();
```

You will need to include `<avr/sleep.h>` in order to have access to the
`sleep_mode()` function. The sleep is likely to be very short though,
probably less than a millisecond, as the ATtiny will be waken up by the
next timer interrupt.

If you want a deeper, longer sleep, you could choose a different sleep
mode in `setup()`:

```cpp
set_sleep_mode(SLEEP_MODE_PWR_DOWN);
```

Read the datasheet if you want to know what wakeup sources are available
in each sleep mode.

Alternatively, if you want to make the ATtiny sleep forever (until the
next power cycle), call `cli()` in order to disable the interrupts,
right before calling `sleep_mode()`.

Comment: Dear Edgar , i am trying to do whats u r saying and i have a good result. Sketch is running for a period set into millis() and then stops. The problem is that led in pinmode 0 remains high for ever. Now i am trying to figure out what i am doing wrong. Normally i desire all pinmodes to be low once sleepmode is activated. i will revert. Thanks again.

Comment: hELLO, i think i solved it. It was easier than i thought. After millis command I set all pinmodes to low digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
digitalWrite(0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(1, LOW);  // 1
  digitalWrite(2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(3, LOW);
  digitalWrite(4, LOW);   after that statement i proceed with sleepmode commands and here we go. All leds stop flashing and no current runs from battery. This is a small victory for me. Thank you so much all.